# Help identifying 3-pin open-collector photo-transistor-like component

Tags: identification, components, photodiode, phototransistor

Can someone help identify the 3 pin photo device (not the entire module) on this "[Icstation 5V Light Sensor Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M8PFZRC)"? (may be same as [this one](http://www.icstation.com/laser-receiver-sensor-module-modulator-tube-laser-sensor-module-p-3207.html)
It seems to act as a photo-transistor, but yet has 3 pins instead of 2. Its nets are labeled (on PCB module) as "GND", "OUT", and "VCC". OUT has a 10k pull-up to VCC --- so seems to be open-collector. But it's a 3-pin device, so is it [some kind](https://physlab.lums.edu.pk/images/1/10/Photodiode_circuit.pdf) of photo-transistor + op-amp/comparator + NPN?
Does anyone have a Manufacturer + Manufacturer Part Number and/or can anyone point me to a datasheet?

Comment: Somebody seems to have [figured it out](https://www.codrey.com/electronic-circuits/the-mysterious-laser-receiver-sensor-module/).

Comment: A photo transistor does have 3 pins. A photodiode has two pins commonly but, can sometimes have three.

Comment: The [IS0203](https://www.codrey.com/electronic-circuits/the-mysterious-laser-receiver-sensor-module/) looks very similar to TT Electronics [OPL530](https://www.ttelectronics.com/TTElectronics/media/ProductFiles/Datasheets/OPL530-550-560.pdf). The IS0203 appears optimized for [900 nm](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32813644324.html), whereas with the OPL530, "Irradiance measurements are made with  λi = 935 nm".

Answer (score 1):

> so is it some kind of photo-transistor + op-amp/comparator + NPN?

Yes, exactly.

According to [this article](https://www.codrey.com/electronic-circuits/the-mysterious-laser-receiver-sensor-module/) by [T.K. Hareendran](https://www.codrey.com/author/tkhareendran/), the sensor is all of these things, like the following:

[image: ISO203 Detector]

I could not find a datasheet.

Often, mass-produced, economy items from China do not have datasheets and are unlikely to have one.  Fine for experimentation only.  If looking for production (or even guaranteed characteristics), will have to find a different device with a datasheet, or incorporate your own [regulator, transimpedance amplifier, and open-collector output transistor].

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have evolved from some other similar product. There's also an 0103 that has <strike>different sensitivity</strike> inverted output. The datasheet below is Japanese so maybe it was an original Japanese product or it was just the Japanese-language datasheet of some other product.

[Here](https://mbb.eet-china.com/blog/3894459-409503.html) is more information but the manufacturer is not shown that I can see. Thanks to @ocrdu for the lead.

[image]

[image]

P.S. the watermark is the blog site, not the manufacturer.

---

Edit:

Okay, it certainly appears to be a clone of a part made by [Kodenshi](http://www.kodenshi.co.jp/english/index.html) of Kyoto, Japan. The datasheet for the very similar PIC0103SL is [here](https://www.kodenshi.co.jp/files/product/PIC0103SL.pdf).